# mmap system call usage

Tags: posix, mmap

I heard about using a mmap system call for merging two blocks of memory into one continuous with MAP_ANONYMOUS flag, but I can't find any simple example how to use this trick.

The example on the Wikipedia which implements an optimized circular buffer, is too complicated for me ([Circular Buffer article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)).

Can you give me any usage example for MAP_ANONYMOUS flag?

Comment: What's your question? You want to implement a circular buffer like the one described in the Wikipedia article (a neat trick, by the way)? You want to use MAP_ANONYMOUS for some other purpose? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to merge two memory blocks into one continuous.

Comment: I don't know what that means. These "two memory blocks" are... 2 different `mmap`ed areas which are not mapped into adjacent pages but you would like them to be? Two different mappings of the same underlying file...? Two mappings of the same physical object (memory or file) which you would like to make adjacent just like is done in the trick demonstrated in the Wikipedia article? Please explain, and show some code if you have.

Comment: Example:
void* part1 = malloc(100);
void* part2 = malloc(250);

void* merged = Merge(part1, part2);  // Size is 350

Is there a way to merge them into one without any reallocating the new block of memory and copy to it. Just get a pointer to "virtual" merged block. I need, for example, use this new merged block in function like printf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the clarification you have provided in your comments, it sounds like you are trying to mis two things that have nothing to do with each other.

```
void *part1 = malloc(100);
void *part2 = malloc(250);
```

You want to manipulate virtual memory so that these two blocks of memory are addressable as 350 contiguous bytes of memory.

This is not possible. First of all, the blocks of memory you have will in general be neither page-aligned nor page-sized. You can only manipulate virtual memory in page-aligned, page-sized chunks. Secondly, even if you are very lucky and they are page-aligned and page-sized, they probably come from the heap area (the area below `brk()`). I don't think you can remap or unmap that area of memory using `mremap()` or `munmap()`. (There are alternate implementations of `malloc()` that get memory from `mmap()` and wouldn't be subject to this problem but they are still subject to the first problem.

But let's say you do have two blocks of memory that are page-aligned, page-sized, and remapable, and you want to remap them so that they are adjacent. Most likely, you obtained those blocks from `mmap()` in the first place. Then you could remap them to adjacent addresses using `mremap()`. Be aware that `mremap()` is Linux-specific though. I'm not aware of a portable way to do this. In pseudocode:

```
/* Map some useless memory just to get the kernel to reserve a range
   of addresses for us which will be big enough for both blocks */
address = mmap(NULL, blocksize1+blocksize2, ..., MAP_ANONYMOUS, ...);

/* remap the first block to the the first address in this new range */
mremap(block1, blocksize1, blocksize1, MREMAP_MAYMOVE|MREMAP_FIXED, address);
/* remap the second block to go right after the first block */
mremap(block2, blocksize2, blocksize2, MREMAP_MAYMOVE|MREMAP_FIXED,
        address+blocksize1);
```